# Extend a circle action on $3$-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, group-actions, 4-manifolds

Let $M$ be an oriented closed $3$-manifold equipped with an effective smooth circle action.

Can we have a classification of all such $M$ such that there exists a $4$-manifold $N$ with $\partial N=M$, and the given circle action on $M$ can be extended to an effective smooth circle action on $N$?

Comment: I don't work in $S^1$-equivariant bordism but there has been some considerable work in this area.  Here is a recent paper on the topic.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04073.pdf

Comment: The quotient of a 3-manifold by a circle action will be an orbifold. If there are no fixed points of the action, then the quotient is a closed orbifold. These are known to be null-cobordant. https://msp.org/pjm/2000/193-1/p04.xhtml One could then try to extend the circle action to an action over the 3-manifold bounding the orbifold (but I haven’t tried to do this myself).